# How can I use React Native AsyncStorage with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context, asyncstorage

I have set a React Context like so:

```
export const TokenContext = createContext({token: ''});
```

and I am using it to create a Provider in my App.js, where I'm trying to first retrieve the token from AsyncStorage:

```
const App = () => {

    const [token, setToken] = React.useState('');

    const retrieveData = async () => {
        const storedToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log(storedToken);
        setToken(storedToken);

        return;
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        retrieveData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <TokenContext.Provider token={token}>
                <RootNav  />
            </TokenContext.Provider>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

I want to consume that Context in the `RootNav` component being used above:

```
const RootNav = () => {
    const token = React.useContext(TokenContext);
    const isSignedIn = !!token;

    return (
        <Root.Navigator>
            {isSignedIn ? (
                <>
                    <Root.Screen name={RouteNames.TAB_NAV} component={TabNav} />
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <Root.Screen
                        name={RouteNames.LOGIN_SCREEN}
                        component={LoginScreen}
                    />
                </>
            )}
        </Root.Navigator>
    );
};
```

However, the token value in the context is undefined even though there is a value in the storage. If I manually pass the prop down to RootNav (without context), I can use it just fine, like so:

App.js

```
...
  return (
        <NavigationContainer>
             <RootNav token={token} />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
```

RootNav.js

```
const RootNav = ({token}) => {
    const isSignedIn = !!token;

    return (
    ...
```

However, I want to use this token in places that are more nested down so I'd rather just use context if I can get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass token with value

```
    <NavigationContainer>
        <TokenContext.Provider value={{token}}>
            <RootNav  />
        </TokenContext.Provider>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

in consumer

```
const {token} = React.useContext(TokenContext);
```

Comment: this was it, thank you. I missed that the prop into the Context Provider should be 'value'

Answer (score -1):

Try using an object instead of a string.